# Problem in Wikipedia API

Tags: php, api, wiki, wikipedia

I have problem using the Wikipedia API. I use this PHP script,

```
<?php
  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
  $xmlDoc->load("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=content&format=xml");

  print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
?>
```

and I have the following result in the browser. Why?

> Warning:
>   DOMDocument::load(http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=content&format=xml)
>   [domdocument.load]: failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0
>   403 Forbidden in D:\Program
>   Files\VertrigoServ\www\wiki\index.php
>   on line 3
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::load()
>   [domdocument.load]: I/O warning :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=content&format=xml"
>   in D:\Program
>   Files\VertrigoServ\www\wiki\index.php
>   on line 3

Comment: Can you get to it in your browser? The code works for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $vars = array(
    'http' => array(
      'user_agent' =>'whatever'));
  $context = stream_context_create($vars);
  libxml_set_streams_context($context);
  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
  $xmlDoc->load("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=content&format=xml");

  print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
?>
```

Don't ask my why a user-agent is required, but I see more & more the same questions here on SO, which all can be fixed by supplying a User-Agent.

---

**edit:**
The following would also work (it does here):

```
<?php
  ini_set('user_agent','whatever');
  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
  $xmlDoc->load("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=content&format=xml");

  print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
?>
```

Perhaps a default setting in PHP for this `user_agent` has been changed?

Answer (score 2):

For MediaWiki's User Agent policy:
http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy